# wxPython: Event method in different module

Tags: python, events, methods, module, wxpython

I have two modules like this (very very simplified):

main.py:

```
from window import *

class MyApp(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, label, pos, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = parent, title = label, pos = pos, size = size) 
        self.Centre()
        create_window(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'Quit application', 
            'Please confirm', wx.YES_NO | wx.NO_DEFAULT | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        if self.dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_YES:
            self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyApp(None, 'MyApp', (0, 0), (740, 640))
    frame.Show()
    frame.SetFocus()
    app.MainLoop()
```

window.py:

```
import wx            

def create_window(self):

    self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    self.fileMenu = wx.Menu()

    self.item = self.fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Quit', 'Quit application')

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnClose, self.item)

    self.menubar.Append(self.fileMenu, '&File')
    self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)

    self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
    self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Ready')
```

Now i would like to move the OnClose method from main.py to window.py (not only this one, if have many other methods in main.py, and I want to move all of them to different modules to make my code more structured).
But just cutting the module from main.py and pasting it in window.py doesn't work (as a was expecting).
So, my question is, what do I have to change in my code to make an event method or another method accessible from another module?

Comment: is create_window a method inside a class or it is as it is shown, a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want. If this is about general behavior you want to implement in your classes (like a particular way of closing them, report state, adding a balloontip system, etc), then one way is to create a class with the corresponding methods and to inherit from her.

```
class BehaviorPack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        whatever
    def OnClose(self, event)
        whatever
    def colour_panel(self):
        whatever
```

then you import that class and inherit from it:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame, BehaviorPack):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        ..........
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a PubSub model (there is one included as part of wxpython/derived from wxpython).

You'd set up a listener (subscriber) in one module and then sent it an event (publish) along with the context in which the event occurs.

This allows for easy separation. They have specific wxpython examples even for you to follow: http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/